# When the whole space $H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$ can be represented by $c(L_t)$ of $X_t$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, chern-classes

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$ be a holomorphic family of $X$ with $X_t=\pi^{-1}(t),t\in B$, and $X_0=X$.

Let $L_t$ be a holomorphic line bundle over $X_t$, then its Chern class $c(L_t)$ is an element in $H^{1,1}(X_t,\mathbb Q)\subset H^2(X_t,\mathbb Q)\cong H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$, here $H^{1,1}(X_t,\mathbb Q)$ is a subgroup $H^2(X_t,\mathbb Q)$ whose elements can be represented by a closed $(1,1)$ form of $X_t$.

My question is: conversely, for any $\alpha\in H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$, under what conditions, does there exists a holomorphic line bundle $L_t$ over $X_t$ such that $c(L_t)=\alpha$?

If the general case is too difficult, it is also good to require $X$ to be Kähler or any other reasonable kind of manifold, does anyone think about this question before?

Added:

The key point is: since $X$ is diffeomorphic to $X_t$, we have an isomorphism $F_t:H^2(X_t,\mathbb R)\cong H^2(X,\mathbb R)$, hence $H^2(X_t,\mathbb Q)\cong H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$, as $c(L_t)\in H^{1,1}(X_t,\mathbb Q)\subset H^2(X_t,\mathbb Q):=H^2(X_t,\mathbb Q)\cap H^{1,1}(X_t)$, where $H^{1,1}(X_t)$ is the subgroup of $H^2(X_t,\mathbb C)$ whose elements are represented by a $(1,1)$ form of $X_t$ (not $X$). Then, in general $F_tH^{1,1}(X_t)$ may not lie in $H^{1,1}(X)\subset H^2(X,\mathbb C)$.

So if $\alpha\in H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$ is represented, for example, by a $(2,0)$ form of $X$, is it always possible for $\alpha$ to be represented by a $(1,1)$ form of $X_t$? Some conditions should be added on the deformation $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$, since if $\pi$ is a trivial deformation, we may not find a $(1,1)$ form of $X_t$ representing $(2,0)$ form of $X$, in conclusion, this should be treated as a question on deformation $X_t$ of $X$.

Comment: Yes, this is actually well-known. A class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is the first Chern class of a line bundle if and only if it is in the kernel of the map $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ associated to the homomorphism of sheaves $\mathbb{Z}_X\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X$. This follows directly from the exponential exact sequence.

Comment: The Lefschetz (1,1) theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_theorem_on_(1,1)-classes says that, on a compact Kahler manifold, if a class $\alpha$ is in $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ and the image of $\alpha$ in $H^2(X, \mathbb{C})$ is representable by a  $(1,1)$ form, then $\alpha$ is the class of a line bundle.

Comment: It is also true on any complex manifold that, for $\alpha \in H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$,   $\alpha$ is the class of a line bundle if and only if maps to $0$ in $H^2(X, \mathcal{O})$. As abx says, this follows from the exponential sequence.

Comment: So the missing gap is, for a class in $H^2(\mathbb{R})$, when is "representable by a closed $(1,1)$-form" equivalent to "maps to $0$ in $H^2(\mathcal{O})$." Do you want people to dig into this, or is it enough of an answer to tell you that, in the compact Kahler case, this is the Lefschetz (1,1) theorem?

Comment: @abx, but I think the essential part is: any closed $2$-form $\alpha$ (which may be of a mixed type of $(2,0)+(1,1)$) is representable by a $(1,1)$ form of $X_t$?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer what I care about is when a general closed $2$-form of $X$ can be represented by a $(1,1)$ form of $X_t$, not $X$, as I have added at the end of my question.

Comment: The question as currently stated is ill-defined, since you did not specify an isomorphism $H^2(X_t,\mathbf Q) \stackrel\sim\to H^2(X,\mathbf Q)$. Rather you specified *existence* of such an isomorphism ― for vector spaces this just means they have the same dimension. There is a little bit of structure in that you require the isomorphism to come from a diffeomorphism $X_t \stackrel\sim\to X$, but there could still be many.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn thanks for pointing out this to me, I agree with you. Actually, I have noticed maybe I need to figure out the isomorphism $F_t:H^2(X,\mathbb Q)\to H^2(X_t,\mathbb Q)$ specifically, but I'm not sure whether it is necessary. If the isomorphism $F_t$ is given, then what is the answer to the problem?

Comment: After shrinking $B$, one may assume that $\mathcal X \cong X \times B$ as smooth manifolds. In that case you obtain isomorphisms on the cohomology by pulling back, so for $F_t$ you might want to go $H^2(X, \mathbb Q) \leftarrow H^2(\mathcal X, \mathbb Q) \to H^2(X_t, \mathbb Q)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still confused. You mention the family $\mathcal{X} \to B$, but the final question is just whether there is a line bundle on $X_t$ with the desired property. Are you asking whether the truth of this condition can depend on $t$? (continued)

Comment: The answer to that is yes, certainly: Let $E_t$ be a family of elliptic curves dependent on $t$ with varying $j$-invariant, and topologically trivial as in red_trumpet's comment. We take $X_t = E_0 \times E_t$. Inside $E_0 \times E_0$, let $\Delta$ be the diagonal and let $\alpha$ be the corresponding class in $H^2(E_0 \times E_0)$. That cohomology class in $E_0 \times E_t$ will not be a $(1,1)$ class for generic $t$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer yes, for the central fibe $X$, I know that $c(L)\in H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Q)\subset H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$, where $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Q):=H^{1,1}(X)\cap H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$, where $H^{1,1}(X)$ is a subspace of $H^2(X,\mathbb C)$ whose elements are representable by $(1,1)$ forms, but for those can't be represented by $(1,1)$ forms, i.e. $H^2(X,\mathbb C)-H^{1,1}(X)$, we consider its deformation $\{X_t\}$, which means can the union $\cup_{t\in B}H^{1,1}(X_t)$ fill the whole space $H^2(X,\mathbb C)$? According to Bruyn, maybe we should specify the isomorphism $F_t:H_{dR}^2(X)\to H_{dR}^2(X_t)$.

Comment: I feel like this conversation is ranging wildly, and we should at some point pause and let you figure out how to focus the question better. (Or maybe someone else understands you better than I do.) As red trumpet says, locally, we have a canonical trivialization. Globally, we have a vector bundle on $B$ whose fiber over $t$ is $H^2(X_t)$ and there is an integrable connection called the "Gauss-Manin connection". For any path from $t_1$ to $t_2$ in $B$, parallel transport along the Gauss-Manin connection gives an identification between $H^2(X_{t_1})$ and $H^2(X_{t_2})$.

Comment: Regarding the question of whether the $(1,1)$ forms can fill up $H^2$. Let's take $B$ simply connected, so we can trivialize globally, and take $\alpha \in H^2(X)$, we ask whether there is some fiber where $\alpha$ is a $(1,1)$ class.

Comment: Here are some obstructions if $\dim H^{11} = 1$. First of all, $H^{11}$ is always fixed by complex conjugation so, if $\alpha$ and $\overline{\alpha}$ are linearly independent in $H^2$, then this can't happen. Also, let's say for simplicity that $\dim X$ is $2$. Then the Hodge index theorem tells us that $\alpha \cup \alpha$ is positive, and that is a purely topological condition. I think you should be able to get similar obstructions out of the higher dimensional Hodge index theorem when $\dim H^{11} =1$ but $\dim X$ is larger.

Comment: I haven't found any obstructions when $\dim H^{11}>1$, but I would imagine they exist.